# Eigenvalues of $U^* diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) U$, $U$ is tall and has orthogonal columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

$U\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times k}, k<n~$ and
$~\lambda_i\in \mathbb{R} ~\forall~ i$

$U^*U=I_k$ but $UU^*$ is unknown.

Note that, $U$ is *tall matrix* formed by a few columns of some *unitary* matrix.

This matrix-form seems to be similar to an Eigen-decomposition,
but I fail to see any relation between the eigenvalues of  $~U^* diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) U~$ and $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots)$

Another observation (if it helps in anyway):

$U^*diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)U$ also appears like a $k\times k$ sub-matrix of another $n\times n$ matrix, unitarily similar to $diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$.

In the worst case, I would want at least the maximum eigenvalue & eigenvector of it.

Comment: Isn't it a singular value decomposition?

Comment: Looks like so, but I need *eigen values*!

Comment: are the $\lambda_i$ complex or real?

Comment: $\lambda_i$ are real values.

Comment: Note also that $U^*diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)U$ is Hermitian and thus its singular values and eigenvalues corresponds (up to sign).

Comment: The answer is probably going to be "it depends". Therefore you need to tell us what kind of information you want (bounds on the possible eigenvalues for instance).

Comment: Okay, in that case, I want the information about the maximum eigenvalue.. (at least bounds if not exact)

Comment: I don't have the time or competence for a proper answer, but just let me state what seem reasonable guesses of what might be true (1) all eigenvalues are still real (2) they are all situated between the minimal and maximal $\lambda_i$ (3) in any interval the number of eigenvalues is not more than the number of $\lambda_i$ in the same interval (4) the maximal eigenvalue could therefore be anything between $\lambda_k$ and $\lambda_n$ (assuming the $\lambda_i$ are in increasing order).

Answer (score 0):

$\min\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}\|x\|^2=\min\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}\|Ux\|^2\leq x^*U^*diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)Ux\leq \max\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}\|Ux\|^2=\max\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}\|x\|^2$

and therefore $\min\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}\leq \lambda_i(S)\leq \max\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ for all the eigenvalues of $S:=U^*diag(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)U$.

Comment: Is $V$ just invertible or is it unitary? If not unitary, eigenvalues of $V^*MV$ are not equal to that of $M$!!

Comment: You are right about my previous answer. I have edited it.